# Can not Login to phpmyadmin "Cookies must be enabled past this point"

Tags: login, cookies

I am having some trouble getting into phpmyadmin when trying to login.  The only error that comes up is "Cookies must be enabled past this point"

I have checked my browser setting to allow cookies.  Our server is running on Ubuntu.

Would anyone have any suggestion onto where to begin looking for solution to this problem.

Comment: How about you try a different web browser?

Answer (score 2):

In the phpmyadmin directory, edit the `config.inc.php` and set a custom `blowfish_secret`, a good random secret can be generated via the [WordPress API salt page](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/), just use one of the constant values.

```
/* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'Your blowfish secret here';
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

That message is displayed if you are using cookie based authentication before you are authenticated and does not mean your credentials are incorrect.

My suggestion of where to start looking is to check your log in credentials are correct by connecting to MySQL with the MySQL client.

```
mysql -u <username> -p
```

and enter the password when prompted.

If you have the correct username and password, then you could try changing the authentication method used by phpMyAdmin to http authentication which will allow you to log in without using cookies.

Comment: Hi Richard,
           I will this a go and let you know how i went. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hey freddy6, any luck with this yet?

Comment: Hi Richard,
           i can log into the mysql database fine from command line, I am just trying to find out how to change the authentication method to http authentication.

Comment: In a file called config.inc.php . You are looking to change the line to look lke this:
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';

Comment: freddy6, did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1):

go to mozilla forefox  `tools->Options->privacy` and then check the option
`accept cookies from sites` and then retry to login into phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. It turns out that virtual machine I was running on was out of disk space. Use the command df -h to determine your disk space and clear up some space.

Answer (score 0):

**Check if you've blocked cookies for localhost** (or the domain where phpMyAdmin is). This is similar to [@diEcho's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/145720/51312), but FF makes it hard to figure out where the cookies are blocked and I like dummie's guides...

Googling for this brings up a [solution in a forum post](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=196577#p196667):

> And... In Firefox, for some unknown reason, local host and 127.0.0.1 were both blocked. Removed this block, and everything OK in Firefox. Had more difficulty clearing the blocks in IE, but in the end managed to get this working.

For Mozilla Firefox (v33):

1. Go to `Tools > Options > Privacy (tab)`
2. Select **Firefox will:** 'Use custom settings for history'
3. Make sure **Accept cookies from sites** is checked on
4. Click **Exceptions...** and look for localhost, make sure that either nothing is there or the Status is **not** 'Block' - if it is blocked then click on the row and click 'Remove Site'
5. Retry to login into phpmyadmin

[image: Privacy options dialog]

[image: Cookie Exceptions dialog]